# `pyenv install 3.8.0`でエラーが出ます。

Tags: python, macos, pyenv

こんにちは。

macでpyenvを使ってpython3.8.0をインストールしようとしたところ、次のエラーが出てしまい、うまくいきません。

```
❯ pyenv install 3.8.0                                  
python-build: use openssl@1.1 from homebrew
python-build: use readline from homebrew
Downloading Python-3.8.0.tar.xz...
-> https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.0/Python-3.8.0.tar.xz
Installing Python-3.8.0...
python-build: use readline from homebrew
python-build: use zlib from xcode sdk

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.15.1 using python-build 20180424)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/4f/xp5nrk812wx6730bfkytvwyw0000gn/T/python-build.20191107221215.27174
Results logged to /var/folders/4f/xp5nrk812wx6730bfkytvwyw0000gn/T/python-build.20191107221215.27174.log

Last 10 log lines:
  "__PyRuntime", referenced from:
      _check_preinit_isolated_config in _testembed.o
  "__Py_Dealloc", referenced from:
      _test_open_code_hook in _testembed.o
      __audit_hook_run in _testembed.o
  "__Py_InitializeMain", referenced from:
      _test_init_main in _testembed.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Programs/_testembed] Error 1
```

エラーログを読んでみたのですがよくわからずに解決できませんでした。

ちなみに、`pyenv --version`は`pyenv 1.2.15`となり、インストールは成功しています。

一つ引っかかるのは、`which pyenv`で、

```
pyenv () {
    local command
    command="${1:-}" 
    if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]
    then
        shift
    fi
    case "$command" in
        (rehash | shell) eval "$(pyenv "sh-$command" "$@")" ;;
        (*) command pyenv "$command" "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```

となってしまっている点です。

試したこととしては、
- pyenvの再インストール(brew)
- shellの再起動
です。
xcodeのコマンドラインツールは入っています。

同様のエラーを解決した方、この手のものにお詳しい方、何卒ご教示ください…

Comment: 全然関係しないのですが、検索すると最近のこんな記事が出てきます。参考になれば。[pyenvを使ったpython環境構築(mac/WSL)](https://hacknote.jp/archives/53760/), [macOS CatalinaにPython3.8をインストールし、セイウチ演算子を試す](https://qiita.com/monhan/items/93802bc868dc67d15a07), [Common build problems](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brew remove binutil`で解決しました。
https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#macos-ld-symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86_64-1245

尚、後半の`which pyenv`は依然として期待値が返りません。

Comment: eval "$(pyenv init -)" を実行した後は pyenv はシェルの関数になるので、質問に書いてある結果で正しいはずですよ。
type pyenv とすれば  shell function であることは確認できるはずです。

Comment: なるほど！それは知りませんでした。ありがとうございます！